# Moving from VS2012 to VS2013 or VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

We are currently using Visual Studio 2012 with .NET framework 4.5. We were planning to upgrade to VS2013 but with "[Visual Studio 2015 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx)" available for download, feeling double mind migrating to VS2013. We normally like to stay with one VS version for ~2 years so like to be sure about the next version we migrate to.

Would like to know from your experience about:

1. Does it make sense to wait for sometime and skip VS 2013?
2. Will there be any consequences we should be aware of moving our codebase to next VS version? Considering these new Visual Studio version will bring new .NET framework version 4.6? I know we can change to old version.

Comment: yes you could wait for 2015...I don't think 2012 and 2013 have much of a differnce but 2015 has more advances comapred to 2012...so eventhough you change to 2013 again you may need to change to 2015 sooner..so better wait for a couple of months and migrate....

Comment: You do realize that this is out-of-scope by definition. As for the two year wait, you do realize it's longer that Visual Studio's and .NET's release cycle? This way you will always be one step behind

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Yes I do realize :) Fortunately or unfortunately Microsoft is making it hard to keep up with their release cycle. We take  reasonable/suitable time to upgrade our toolset.

Comment: I wouldn't blame Microsoft but the *extremely long wait*. The *entire industry* is moving far faster than Internet time, with new library versions coming every few months, *especially* in Javascript, the hottest language right now. Cloud platforms update quarterly or faster. If anything, MS is slower than the rest but catching up. The .NET Framework is already updated through Nuget packages to allow faster releases and VS is moving to a yearly release cycle. 2 years makes it hard to follow the market or may even drive you out of it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I agree with you brother! With my statement "We normally like to stay with one VS version for ~2 years" I thought I did not stressed on 2 year as number. Before VS2012, it was a reasonable time. You are right, VS is changing fast now than before so should we.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next preview version of Visual Studio 2015 will be a "go-live" licensed version, which means you'll be able to use it for production code. This also means that the next release will probably be soon:

> [image] **Brian Harry MS** Wed, Apr 1 2015 12:39 PM #
>
> @Daniel, We're working on it.  We recently cut a branch for our next preview build (and it includes Team Project rename).  We've got some work to do to fix some bugs and really validate it - because this next preview is "go-live".  We'll get it out to you as soon as we can.
>
> Brian
>
> <sup>Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2015/02/23/vs-2015-ctp6-and-tfs-2015-ctp1-shipped-today.aspx</sup>

.NET 4.6 is an in place upgrade of the .NET framework, which may cause some issues, [these are documented in the preview release notes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx) (though additional items may be added all the way up until release). In the past we've had issues where people were using a very specific overloads or events that had slight changes between .NET versions. We've had situations where classes were marked Obsolete and needed to be updated. Some people use Reflection and call into code they should not use, these may break without warning. On a more specific level, changes in operating system, etc. [This blog talks about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx).

Personally, if I had the choice, I'd opt for the latest version. [If only for the license changes that are coming for 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx), which put lot of 2013 ultimate features in Professional and what used to be Premium.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really helpful. Just wondering about "which may cause some issues" part, the link does not provide info around potential issue. Any example?

Comment: @SBirthare Typically the breaking changes between framework versions are very minor, but if your application happens to rely on one of the differences it can break. I recommend simply trying your application on the new framework and fix any problems that occur (should be rare).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could wait for 2015...I don't think 2012 and 2013 have much of a difference but 2015 has more advances compared to 2012...so eventhough you change to 2013 again you may need to change to 2015 sooner..so better wait for a couple of months and migrate....

Comment: Actually, there *are* a lot of *significant* differences. The performance profiler in VS 2013 is far better for one thing, with far better support for concurrent programming (ie Tasks, PLINQ). On the other hand, if you waited for 2 years before installing 2013, waiting a few more months won't hurt more

Comment: can you please elaborate more on the differences?